# Google Glass Application development startup on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I am an Android Developer and I want to start working on Google Glass application. I have installed Eclipse in my computer but I learnt that it will not work for Google Glass development. Some blogs suggested I should use Eclipse Indigo.

I have checked and installed Eclipse Indigo and ADT and other plugins.

I am trying to run my glass on debug mode but system is not detecting it.

Can anybody please help me with how to set proper environment for Google Glass and how to make it detect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that you have to do first:

1. Install the Glass Development Kit preview via the SDK Manager (Should be under the 4.4.2 platform).
2. Ensure that you have Debug mode enabled on your Glass. After enabling Debug mode when you plug Glass in for the first time you should be asked if you'd like to trust the computer on the Glass. I select Always Allow so I don't get asked multiple times.

By the way, I am using Eclipse Kepler (but mostly IntelliJ), so I doubt that the version is critical.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jessie. There was some glass driver issue on my computer. I just formatted it and did whole process again and it detected my glass well.